# Identify jquery version of the code

Tags: jquery

i am trying to find the jquery version that is used in the existing code.  Some of the code has the below syntax.  Trying  to understand which syntax is an old jquery version

**File1**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    });
});
```

**File2**

```
(function($) {


})(jQUery);
```

Comment: the way how you init jquery has nothing to do with its version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how you wrap or init your code has nothing to do with the jQuery version. The two examples you posted are completely different in their intent.

```
jQuery(function($)

    $(document).ready(function(){
    });
});
```

This basically fires two times the `ready()` event since `$(function() {});` is a short for that, writing `$` once as `jQuery` and then pass `$` as argument was the old way of doing it, but it still works with newer versions of jQuery, it is just not recommended.

The second example is just an anonymous function wrapper, it executes because of the nature of anon functions, not because you told jQuery to do stuff on `ready()`. But also, this is not version depended.

The "best" way is doing it like so:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        // doc ready
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If you simply need to find out the currently used jQuery version use this:

```
$.fn.jquery;
```